# Copy filtered rows with the criteria 4, 5, 8, 10, 11 ,12, 13

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the lines with the criteria 4, 5, 8, 10, 11 ,12, 13 to a separate sheet (2019_Rücktrans).

```
Sub Copy()
Dim variable As String
variable = "2019"

With Sheets(variable).UsedRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=Array("4", "5", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13")
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With
Sheets("2019_Rücktrans").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues
Sheets(variable).UsedRange.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

**Error Message:**

> Run Time Error 1004 AutoFilter method of Range class failed

Comment: I think AutoFilter is missing `, Operator:=xlFilterValues` at the end https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter

Comment: Thx Buddy for your help. Added the additional syntax but no improve, still: Autofield Method of Range class failed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should help you achieve your desired result, it has to do with using the  Operator statement with the Filter, so it doesn't simply filter to the last value of the Array but actually filter by all values in the Array:

```
Sub Copyit()
Dim variable As String
Dim LastRow As Long
variable = "2019"
LastRow = Sheets("2019_Rücktrans").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With Sheets(variable).UsedRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=Array("4", "5", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("2019_Rücktrans").Range("A" & LastRow)
End With
Sheets(variable).UsedRange.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Further to the comment, a way to verify that the filter is not currently set would be to add the following  at the top of the code:

```
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2019_Rücktrans").ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Tried your version, still the same issue as before: Autofield Method of Range class failed.

Comment: @OliverPareth is the data filtered when you execute the code?

Comment: no it isn't. It hangs with the line: .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=Array("4", "5", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13")
yellow highlighted there. 
Thx man, appreciate your help!

Comment: @OliverPareth I've tested the code and it doesn't give me any errors, I'm unsure as to what is causing the error, but it might help if you are able to upload a copy of your workbook to something like GoogleDrive and comment a link to it, so I may have a closer look?

Comment: *Sub Copy()
Dim variable As String
variable = "2019"

With Worksheets(variable).UsedRange
 -->   .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=Array("4", "5", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With
Sheets("2019_Rücktrans").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues
Sheets(variable).UsedRange.AutoFilter
End Sub*
where the --> is, the compiler feels upset

Comment: @OliverPareth is your data in Columns A to V in the worksheet "2019"? are there any gaps in your UsedRange, as in any empty columns or rows? Might be worth replacing UsedRange with something like `Worksheets(variable).Range("A1:V50")` and then check if that works?

Comment: the data I want to be filtered is in Column V . I have a celllink from several combo boxes to the V column which show the status of our product (more or less: new, used, ready to be shipped back). I want a sheet (2019), where I can see the actual stock list with what is in the warehouse. Things which are ready to be shipped back should be copied into the 2019_Rücktrans, for documentation/statistic purposes.

Comment: @OliverPareth but does the code work if you replace UsedRange with an actual Range? or does it still give you the same error? It's hard to suggest something when I can't replicate the issue.....

Comment: I tried to define the range with Worksheets(variable).Range("A1:V300"), same Range class issue.